# How can I perform operations on smartpy sp.TBytes?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm currently trying to perform on-chain image mutation. I'm writing the smart contract using smartpy.

The idea is:

- The image is on-chain "Raw PPM encoded", in `sp.TBytes` format. Each pixel is represented by 3 consecutives RGB bytes
- The contract has an entrypoint that takes a pseudo-random pixel from the image and changes its value

To modify a pixel of the image, I then have to use `sp.slice` on the image to isolate the pixel, mutate it, and then reconstruct the image by concatenating:

1. bytes before pixel
2. mutated pixel
3. bytes after mutated pixel.

However, I have troubles when it comes to mutate the pixel's value.

Since there is no operator allowing arithmetic operations on `sp.TBytes`, I would like to transform pixel's value in `sp.TNat`.

I naively wanted to use `sp.unpack` method, but it seems that it assumes the `sp.TBytes` sequence contains a header.

What would then be the solution to perform some operations on a `sp.TBytes` sequence?

Answer (score 2):

What kind of mutation do you want to feature? There is currently no arithmetic operation on bytes but you can compare and concatenate bytes which might be enough for your use case.

Or you can switch to `sp.TNat` by replacing splicing by Euclidean division.

Or you can wait for [bitwise operators](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/alpha.html#michelson-opcodes-for-logical-operations-on-bytes) to be added (they are currently available in the Alpha version of the protocol which powers Mondaynet).

Or you can wait for [operators for conversion between `sp.TNat` and `sp.TBytes`](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/6681) to be added.

Or you can implement the conversion yourself in SmartPy. All you need are two constant maps storing the mappings in both directions.

Comment: I did not decide yet which kind of manipulation I want to do, but it woul involve adding/dividing/modulating pixel values. I did not know that such features were planned for Tezos, thank you for the information. I actually found the following Utils lib doing what I waned to do. It seems they are using pack and unpack by formatting the sp.TBytes themselves. https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils/blob/main/smartpy/README.md

Comment: Thank you for the link ;)